# Setting up Subversion on Windows as a service

Tags: svn, version-control

When installing subversion as a service, I used this command:

```
c:\>svnservice -install --daemon --root "c:\documents and settings\my_repository"
```

And then I got this error:

```
Could not create service in service control manager.
```

After looking at some MSDN docs on the service control manager, I tried granting full control to everyone in the permissions on the registry key at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services, but that hasn't had any effect.

Anybody know what I did wrong, or how to overcome this?

*Note #1: I am running as an administrator on this box*

*Note #2: I was following the instructions given [here](http://blogs.vertigosoftware.com/teamsystem/archive/2006/01/16/Setting_up_a_Subversion_Server_under_Windows.aspx), so maybe my choice of directory is misguided.  And my repository is not actually called "my_repository".  I used the name of an actual project which is currently under source control in *gasp* VSS.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server) installs as a Windows service. It is free, includes Apache, OpenSSL, and a repository / permission management tool. It can also integrate with Active Directory for user authentication. I highly recommend it for hosting SVN on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I've followed the instructions given at the Collabnet site:

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/windows-service.txt

They use the windows SC to create the service (which runs svnserve).  This has worked for me without any problems (using svn 1.4 and 1.5)

Answer (score 1):

I think svnservice is obsolete, because since 1.4, svnserve itself has been able to run as a Windows service.  (svnserve comes as a part of the normal SVN binary distribution)

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/windows-service.txt contains the details of how to set it up.

And the binaries you want are here:  http://subversion.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=91

But as others have said, there are now more friendly packages containing the svn stuff - VisualSVN Server (so badly named it makes me weep) and the Collabnet distribution - the later is Apache only, and is hand rolled on the thighs of virgins, which means that it always seems to appear about three weeks later than everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the command line installer for this.  I assume you are downloading the latest from:

http://svnservice.tigris.org/

I run the installer, and then use the configuration tool (in the Start Menu, SVN Service, SVN Service Administration) to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can currently think of, is the following: make sure you're running under an administrator account. That's absolutely necessary to install a service, AFAIK.

Have fun with Subversion, btw :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you move your repository to somewhere a little safer, maybe "c:\SVNRepo".

I'd hesitate to put the Repository in "Documents and Settings".  Is your repository actually called "my_repository"?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you tu use [Visual SVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/). Very easy to install